# Linking tables with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want tables linked on MySQL, so that when any of three tables are changed the actual table is changed, a bit like doing symlinks or pointers. How can this be done within MySQL? I will be accessing it from php.

Comment: you need to abstract your database class to and create a method to do so. how does your tables look like

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of a good reason for mirroring tables like this.

Comment: The point is so that the authentication tables all in one database with different prefixes for three drupal sites can all be converged so the same login details work from any drupal site, and I will write my own code to transfer to other drupal sites with keyed urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved with database triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: This could be a way of doing what I want to do. I made a comment above about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such native feature in MySQL, but you can accomplish it by writing [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers, so that if one table is modified the others are updated. See [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

Or if the tables just use the same data, then you can have one 'real' table and the rest as views. See [MySQL views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).